# How to pass "..." arguments to a function called from foreach()?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

The following code produces the warning:

```
Warning message:
<anonymous> : <anonymous>: ... may be used in an incorrect context: ‘mean(x[l], ...)’

doForeach <- function(x, ...)
{
    require(doSNOW)
    require(foreach)
    cl <- snow::makeCluster(2, type="MPI")
    on.exit(snow::stopCluster(cl))
    registerDoSNOW(cl)
    do.i <- function(i) lapply(seq_len(length(x)), function(l) mean(x[l], ...))
    foreach(i=seq_len(10)) %dopar% { do.i(i) }
}
x <- rnorm(20)
r <- doForeach(x, trim=1)
```

I'd guess that it comes from the fact that the workers/slaves do not see the `...` anymore. Formal arguments are typically passed as character vectors via `.export=c("<arg>")`, but that does not seem to work for `...` arguments.

What's the correct way of dealing with `...` arguments in this example?

Comment: It would help to pare this down as far as possible, while still generating the error.  The `doSNOW` and `foreach` packages may not be necessary to duplicate the problem, which would greatly simplify the question -- and may lead to a much quicker solution.  The problem may be that `lapply` also specifies `...`.

Comment: If you replace `dopar` by `do`, the computations are done sequentially -- and then it works, so it probably comes from `foreach`.

Comment: Okay, I just simplified the example a bit and explained where I believe the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, apparently the `...` arguments have to be passed via `do.i`. Here is a more obvious (and correctly running) example:

```
doForeach <- function(x, ...)
{
    require(doSNOW)
    require(foreach)
    cl <- snow::makeCluster(2, type="MPI")
    on.exit(snow::stopCluster(cl))
    registerDoSNOW(cl)
    do.i <- function(i, ...) lapply(seq_len(length(x)), function(l) max(x[l], ...))
    foreach(i=seq_len(5)) %dopar% { do.i(i, ...) }
}
x <- 1:3
doForeach(x, 1.5)
```